# Options to make jQuery Ajax code more efficient / logical

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML to display content pulled from an ajax script (ajax.php):

### HTML

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="var_adjectives"><li><a href='#'>Loading...</a></li></ul>
<button id="37" onclick='update_adjectives();'>Refresh</button>

<hr />

<ul class="list-unstyled" id="var_brands"><li><a href='#'>Loading...</a></li></ul>
<button id="37" onclick='update_brands();'>Refresh</button>

<hr />

<ul class="list-unstyled" id="var_clothes"><li><a href='#'>Loading...</a></li></ul>
<button id="37" onclick='update_clothes();'>Refresh</button>

<hr />
```

When the page first loads, the following JS is used to populate the list items against the relevant `<ul>` tag (passing in two parameters each time):

### Javascript Page Load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.post('ajax.php',{u:37,n:1} ,function(data){ var this_record = data.output; $('#var_adjectives').html(this_record);},'json');
    $.post('ajax.php',{u:37,n:33},function(data){ var this_record = data.output; $('#var_brands').html(this_record);},'json');
    $.post('ajax.php',{u:37,n:67},function(data){ var this_record = data.output; $('#var_clothes').html(this_record);},'json');
});
```

The `refresh` button can be used to refresh the content in the relevant `<ul>` tag, calling the following relevant JS function, from the `onclick` event on each of the 3 buttons:

### Javascript Refresh Functions

```
function update_adjectives() {
    $.post('ajax.php'
         , {u:37,n:1}
         , function(data){ var this_record = data.output; $('#var_adjectives').html(this_record); }
         , 'json')
};

function update_brands() { 
    $.post('ajax.php'
         , {u:37,n:33}
         , function(data){ var this_record = data.output; $('#var_brands').html(this_record); }
         , 'json')
};

function update_clothes() {
    $.post('ajax.php'
         , {u:37,n:67}
         , function(data){ var this_record = data.output; $('#var_clothes').html(this_record); }
         , 'json')
};
```

As you can see, there is a lot of overlap in the basic design of the JS.

I have these questions:

1. I am stuck working out how I can end up with one single line in the block of JS used to populate content when the page first loads.
2. I'd like to only have 1 function used to refresh content - because in my example above I have 3 blocks, but in my real page I have about 30 blocks.

While the JS is created by the PHP code when the page loads (rather than me writing it long-hand), it still would be nice to have much cleaner code which avoids having e.g. 30 refresh functions and 30 lines of code to populate each of the different `<ul>` IDs when first loading the page.

In each case, I can see I would need to pass an ID of relevant `<ul>` but I am tied up in knots working out if I can achieve what I'm trying to do.

Probably there are many things wrong with using the `onclick` event too!

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: First, `id` attributes are unique and should not be duplicated. Second, It appears from your URLs that your design requires you to call for each `{u:N, n:N}` combo. So, first question: Is there a single endpoint that allows you to collect all the data to be placed on the first rendering? Second question: where does the `n` value come from (did I miss it above somewhere - or populated in PHP)?

Comment: third Q: what's the purpose of the `<a>` tags? Appears to be literally nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely blocker is your API endpoint design. According to what you posted, you must access one category at a time and that must be done by sending the `{u:N,n:N}` combo object as the body of the POST request.

It would simplify things greatly if your endpoint accepted a different object. Something like `{category:'name'}` would allow greater flexibility.

You could use `{category: 'all'}` for the initial view of all categories and use `{category: 'clothes'}` for individual categories for the update/refresh.

Extending that to the click of the refresh buttons. You can use a single event handler and event bubbling to deal with every button click.

First you would add the event handler to containing element for all the `<ul>` elements.

Given this layout:

```html
<div id='container'>
  <ul><li><span>loading...</span></li></ul>
  <button data-category="adjectives">Refresh</button>
  <ul><li><span>loading...</span></li></ul>
  <button data-category="brands">Refresh</button>
  <ul><li><span>loading...</span></li></ul>
  <button data-category="clothes">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

You can react to all the button clicks like this:

```
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', update);
```

The `update()` event handler can determine which button was clicked by checking out the `data-` attribute on the button. Then, make the AJAX request and place the data into the correct `<ul>` by finding the closest or the `prev()` sibling `<ul>` element.

```js
function update() {
  const category = this.dataset.category;
  $.post('ajax.php', {category: category}
    , function(data) {
    $('button').data(category).prev('ul').html(data.output);
  }, 'json')
};
```

Comment: Thank you Randy for your very helpful reply.